# RXJava stop current stream until other one finish

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

i'm having a problem with rx java.

I have a current stream that in some point gives to me an Either

That response has external resources, like image urls, and i want to send each url to an external class, download it asyncronously, and if all of them are ok, continue with that either received or if one of that resources fails while is being downloaded return an Either.error(MyError());

My problem is that as i'm creating a new observable inside the resources provider, it needs to be subscribed to start run, but i do not know how can i do.

This is my current code (not sure if compiles but you get the idea):

```
    private Observable<Either<Error, Response>> prefetchResourcesOrError(final Either<Error, Response> errorOrResponse) {
        if (errorOrResponse.isResponseWithImages()) {
            ResponseImages responseImages = (ResponseImages) responseImages.getResponse();
            return 
             Observable.fromIterable(responseImages.getResources()
                    .map(resourcesProvider::prefetch)
                    .onErrorReturn(throwable -> Observable.<Either<Error, Response>>just(Either.left(new MyError())))
                    .map(observable -> errorOrResponse);
        } else {
            return Observable.just(errorOrResponse);
        }
    }


//Resource prefetch method

    Observable prefetch(Resource resource) {
        return Observable.just(resource)
                .flatMap((Function<Resource, ObservableSource<?>>) res1 ->
                        Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<Void>) emitter ->
                                        resourceLoader.prefetch(res1.getUrl(), new ImageLoaderListenerAdapter() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onException(Exception e) {
                                                emitter.onError(e);
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onResourceReady() {
                                                emitter.onNext(null);
                                            }
                                        })
                                )
                );
    }
}


//The main Stream
//MainObservable is an Either<Error, Response> errorOrResponse
return mainObservable.flatMap(this::prefetchResourcesOrError);
```

Comment: I guess you should subscribe to the main stream

Comment: Main stream is subscribed from elsewhere. It's currently working but now I want to add the explained case.

Comment: Well, you should just use `flatMap`, and you don't need to subscribe to the inner `Observable`

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Doing that I have now does not work and is just a flstmap

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Basically the main stream is not waiting until the other one finish and the resourceLoader is not loading anything.

Comment: Consider that if you are using `rx-java2` a null item is not allowed. You did `emitter.onNext(null);`

Comment: Changed by a new Object fails as well.